# Cannot update a component (component) while rendering a different component (`Controller`) using react-hook-form et shadcnui

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to make an upload file input with

- shadcnui
- react-hook-form
- zod
- nextjs

But when i validate the form, the console give me this error.

I already found the main problem. It's the onChange fonction of the field but i can't use other solution here

Here the stack trace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acpp8.jpg)

And here is a piece of code but i don't think i can make a sandbox for reproduce

```
 <Form {...form}>
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(submit)}>
<FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name="thumbnail_id"
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                    render={({field}) => (
                                        <FormItem className="grid w-full gap-1.5 py-4">
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <FormFileInput
                                                    label={"Thumbnail"}
                                                    field={field}
                                                    isLoading={isLoading}
                                                    name="thumbnail_id"
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
```

```
const FormFileInput = (
    {label, field, isLoading}: Props
) => {

    const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
    const [file, setFile] = useState<string>("")

    const onFileChange = async (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.files?.[0] && file === "") {
            const file = event.target.files[0]
            const {data, success} = await uploadFile(file)
            if (success) {
                setFile(data.uuid)
            }else {
                setFile("")
            }
        }
    }

    const deleteFile = async () => {
        const req = await fetch(`/api/upload/`, {
            method: "DELETE"
        })

        const res = await req.json()

        if (res.success) {

        }
    }

    const pickFile = () => {
        ref.current?.click()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        field.onChange(file)
    }, [file])

    return (
        <>
            <FormLabel>
                {label}
            </FormLabel>
            <Button type="button" onClick={pickFile}>
                Choisissez un fichier
            </Button>
            <Input
                accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .svg, .gif, .mp4"
                type="file"
                ref={ref}
                onChange={onFileChange}
                className="hidden"
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default FormFileInput
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Yikes!  Don't use `<form>` when using a Forms library like RHF.  The whole point to using a Forms library is to NOT use `<form>`.  The `<form>` engages behaviours in the browser that you do NOT want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i've just follow the docs : [link](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/form). I'll try your proposale and come back to give the results

Comment: Did you see on that docs page this statement: "Since FormField is using a controlled component, you need to provide a default value for the field. See the React Hook Form docs to learn more about controlled components."